# finding a y value whose x value is closest to zero in R vectors

Tags: r, function, curve

I have two columns of numbers. First column is called `ddd` and second column `post`. You can easily import my data into your Rstudio this way:

```
id <- "0B5V8AyEFBTmXM1VIYUYxSG5tSjQ"
Points <- read.csv(paste0("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=",id,"&export=download"))
```

My question is how I can find out first, what is `post` when `ddd` is 0 AND second, if there is no 0 for `post` when `ddd` is 0, find the closest to 0? (so I need R to do the both checks for me?)

I have used the following R code which doesn't work:

```
Points$post[Points$ddd == 0]
```

Comment: I get error `InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'`

Comment: @akrun, let me check please.

Comment: Please post a small reproducible example using `dput` i.e. `dput(head(Points, 10))`

Comment: There is no `ddd` with value 0 in the example. Do you want to check with `post` ?

Comment: @RonakShah, yes these are from a function there may or may not be. So that's what I'm asking I need R to first check if there is a ddd with value "0" and if not then it gives me the closest to "0"?

Comment: @akrun, I guess that probably has been an internet issue that you couldn't see the data, it is from a very complex 2000-line code function, but also try this:  `id <- "0B5V8AyEFBTmXM1VIYUYxSG5tSjQ";
Points <- read.csv(sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", id))`

Comment: @parvinkarimi you have the case of when zero is not zero in R due to floating point numbers, see the output of `which((Points$ddd == 0) == T)` vs. `which((as.integer(Points$ddd) == 0) == T)`.  See the section on the link titled "Don't test floating point numbers for exact equality." http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/03/when-is-a-zero-not-a-zero.html

Comment: `with(Points, post[abs(ddd) == min(abs(ddd))])`

Comment: I appreciate everyone's valuable input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `Points` dataframe with two columns, `post` and `ddd`, zero or near zero could be acheived with `which.min(abs(Points$ddd))` which will return the index so `Points$post[which.min(abs(Points$ddd))]` should get you there.

Note, you will have issues if you have multiple zeros or minimum values.